# Как сделать круглый прогресс бар и анимировать его с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Есть круг с рамкой:

[image: круг]

Надо чтобы длина рамки плавно уменьшалась (как прогрессбар), но обычный `border` не имеет параметра длины, есть только ширина.

Думаю, что для этого может подойти тег `<hr>`, которому можно уменьшать как длину так и ширину, но я не знаю, как сделать его изогнутым.

И нет, это конечно можно сделать используя SVG или `canvas`, но меня интересует именно реализация на HTML, CSS.

Есть какие то мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: сделать два дива, один внутри другого, оба скруглённые. один с голубым фоном, другой с серым. И у второго рисовать сектор при помощи linear-gradient. и все

Comment: рисовать сектор?

Comment: ну да, сектор. он же может быть 1%, а может 99%. а так как по z-index див в виде сектора всегда будет находиться за кругом - то в итоге будет получаться прогресс бар

Comment: @СергейМишин и как градиент анимировать?

Comment: @СергейМишин без перерисовки элемента с помощью js

Comment: ну как как, анимация же есть в css

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.circle>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.outer {
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 50% 0, 50% 50%, 50% 50%);
}

.inner {
  transform: scale(0.95);
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

.circle:hover .outer {
  animation: xxx 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes xxx {
  12.5% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 0 0, 50% 50%, 50% 50%);
  }
  25% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 50%, 0 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%);
  }
  37.5% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 50% 100%, 50% 100%, 50% 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%);
  }
  62.5% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%);
  }
  75% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%);
  }
  87.5% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 50% 50%, 50% 50%);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 50%, 50% 50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="outer"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Можно посмотреть как вырезается:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.circle > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.outer {
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 50% 0, 50% 50%);
}

.inner {
  transform: scale(0.95);
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.circle:hover .outer {
  animation: xxx 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes xxx {
  12.5% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 0 0, 50% 50%);
  }

  25% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 50%, 0 50%, 50% 50%);
  }
  
  37.5% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 50% 50%);
  }
  
  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 50% 100%, 50% 100%, 50% 50%);
  }
  
  62.5% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 50%);
  }
  
  75% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 50% 50%);
  }
  
  87.5% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 50% 50%);
  }
  
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="outer"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: можно что-нибудь с этим придумать. С `hr` не получится.

Comment: Почти то что нужно, но рамка должна увеличиваться/уменьшаться в длинне только с 1 стороны и во время анимации у неё всегда должны быть квадратные края, а не прямоугольные

Comment: В этом и основная проблема. Без костылей(делать 2 элемента каждый по 50% блока со своими характеристиками и т.д.) лично у меня не получается, но мне кажется, что это реализуемо, будто нечто похожее но в другой реализации уже видел

Comment: Большое спасибо =)

Answer (score 5):

Но почему обязательно только CSS решение?
SVG именно и существует для реализации графики и прекрасно поддерживает все правила CSS.

Это CSS наоборот не может сделать всё, что подвластно SVG.

Если есть затруднения в использовании SVG, то можно создать в векторном редакторе, буквально в несколько кликов фигуру SVG, скопировать `path`, а всю анимацию перенести  в CSS.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример анимации  звезды смотрите внизу топика.

*Сравните на сколько код стал короче и понятней.*
Разметка везде одинаковая, необходимо только точно узнать полную длину контура svg фигуры и прописать соответствующие параметры `stroke-dasharray` `stroke-dashoffset`

**Первый пример стирания линии**

реализован с помощью увеличения `stroke-dashoffset` от нуля до максимума `628px`

Серый квадрат показывает границы холста SVG, синий прямоугольник контейнер для SVG.

```css
.circle {
position:relative;
width:215px;
height:250px;
background:#CDE9FF;
}
.svg1 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
#circ {
fill:#E0E0E0;
stroke:#03A9F4;
stroke-width:6;
stroke-dasharray:628;
stroke-dashoffset:0;
}
#circ:hover {
animation: progress 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
100% {stroke-dashoffset:628;}
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

<svg class="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="210" height="210" viewBox="0 0 210 210" style="border:1px solid gray" >  

<circle  id="circ" transform="rotate(-90 105 105)" cx="105" cy="105" r="100" />
</svg>

</div>
```

**Второй пример `stroke-dasharray`**

```css
.circle {
position:relative;
width:215px;
height:250px;
background:#CDE9FF;
}
.svg1 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
#circ {
fill:#E0E0E0;
stroke:purple;
stroke-width:6;
stroke-dasharray:628,0;
stroke-dashoffset:-628;
}
#circ:hover {
animation: progress 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
100% {stroke-dasharray:0,628;}
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

<svg class="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="210" height="210" viewBox="0 0 210 210" style="border:1px solid gray" >  

<circle  id="circ" transform="rotate(-90 105 105)" cx="105" cy="105" r="100" />
</svg>

</div>
```

**Третий пример анимация стирания двумя линиями**

Меняем только атрибуты `stroke-dasharray`

```css
.circle {
position:relative;
width:215px;
height:250px;
background:#CDE9FF;
}
.svg1 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
#circ {
fill:#E0E0E0;
stroke:purple;
stroke-width:6;
stroke-dasharray:314,0 314,0;
stroke-dashoffset:-157;
}
#circ:hover {
animation: progress 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
100% {stroke-dasharray:0,314 0,314;}
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
<svg class="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="210" height="210" viewBox="0 0 210 210" style="border:1px solid gray" >  
<circle  id="circ" transform="rotate(-90 105 105)" cx="105" cy="105" r="100" />
</svg>

</div>
```

**Или наоборот рисовать двумя линиями из одной точки**

Для этого надо только поменять местами параметры `stroke-dasharray`

```css
.circle {
position:relative;
width:215px;
height:250px;
background:#CDE9FF;
}
.svg1 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
#circ {
fill:#E0E0E0;
stroke:purple;
stroke-width:6;
stroke-dasharray:0,314 0,314;
stroke-dashoffset:314;
}
#circ:hover {
animation: progress 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
100% {stroke-dasharray:0,0 628,0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
<svg class="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="210" height="210" viewBox="0 0 210 210" style="border:1px solid gray" >  
<circle  id="circ" transform="rotate(-90 105 105)" cx="105" cy="105" r="100" />
</svg>

</div>
```

**Анимация рисования сторон шестиугольника из одной точки**

```css
.circle {
position:relative;
width:215px;
height:250px;
background:#CDE9FF;
}
.svg1 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
#hex {
fill:#E0E0E0;
stroke:purple;
stroke-width:6;
stroke-dasharray:0,300 0,300;
stroke-dashoffset:300;
}
#hex:hover {
animation: progress 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
100% {stroke-dasharray:0,0 600,0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
<svg class="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="210" height="210" viewBox="0 0 210 210" style="border:1px solid gray" >  
<path id="hex" d="m105 5 86.6 50 0 100L105 205 18.4 155l0-100z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

**Анимация лучей звезды**

```css
.circle {
position:relative;
width:215px;
height:250px;
background:#CDE9FF;
}
.svg1 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
#star {
fill:#E0E0E0;
stroke:purple;
stroke-width:6;
stroke-dasharray:0,332 0,332;
stroke-dashoffset:332;
}
#star:hover {
animation: progress 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
100% {stroke-dasharray:0,0 664,0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
<svg class="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="210" height="210" viewBox="0 0 210 210" style="border:1px solid gray" >  
<path id="star" d="m105 5 29.4 59.5 65.7 9.5-47.6 46.4 11.2 65.5L105 155 46.2 185.9 57.4 120.5 9.9 74.1 75.6 64.5Z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Прекрасное решение. А нужен был именно css так как это было условие задачи.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT , подскажи что за софт на первом скриншоте?

Comment: @Shilgen    Векторный редактор [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/ru/release/inkscape-0.92.4/)

Answer (score 3):

```css
.progress-bar-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}

.center-circle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: grey;
  transform: translate3d(15px, 15px, 0);
  z-index: 3;
}

.sector {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(7px, 7px, 0);
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-image: linear-gradient(108deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
  animation: background 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes background {
  15% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(126deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
  }
  25% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
  }
  50% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
  }
  75% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 50%, green 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
  }
  100% {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
  <div class="center-circle"></div>
  <div class="sector"></div>
</div>
```

```
 /* 10% = 126deg = 90 + ( 360 * .1 ) */
```

Если хочется изменять значение по 1, то придется изменять значение  `background-image: linear-gradient` от 90 до 450 в каждом фрейме.

Comment: Небольшая проблема: как я знаю использовать background в keyframes плохо по причине производительности, но всё равно хорошее решение